# Missing jar files in Eclipse RCP 4.4.2 (Luna SR2) SDK, delta pack and language pack

Tags: jar, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, java-8, eclipse-luna

We have an Eclipse RCP based GUI application based on Eclipse SDK 3.7.2 and compiled using Java 7. We are migrating the code base to Java8. We are also migrating Eclipse version to 4.4.2 (Luna SR2) as Eclipse supports Java8 starting 4.4.

I have downloaded eclipse-4.4.2-delta-pack.zip and eclipse-SDK-4.4.2-win32.zip and built language pack using BabelLanguagePack-eclipse-de_4.4.0.v20141223043836.zip as well as Babel packages available for other products, but am not able to find some jar files in the 4.4.2 packages that were present in 3.7.2 packages. I have listed them below:

**Missing jar files in 4.4.2 SDK that were present in 3.7.2 SDK:**
    org.eclipse.update.core*.jar
    org.eclipse.help.appserver_*.jar
    org.eclipse.swt.gtk.hpux.ia64_32*.jar

```
org.eclipse.update.core*.jar
org.eclipse.help.appserver*.jar
```

**Missing jar files in 4.4.2 delta pack that were present in 3.7.2 delta pack:**
    org.eclipse.swt.carbon.macosx*.jar

```
org.eclipse.update.core*.jar
```

**Missing jar files in 4.4.2 Luna language packs (Babel project version R0.12.1 for Luna) that were present in 3.7.2 delta pack**
    org.eclipse.core.contenttype.nl_de*.jar
    org.eclipse.core.expressions.nl_de*.jar
    org.eclipse.core.jobs.nl_de*.jar
    org.eclipse.core.runtime.nl_de*.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.app.nl_de*.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.common.nl_de*.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.preferences.nl_de*.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.registry.nl_de*.jar

Few questions about the missing jar files:

1. Are these jar files no longer part of core eclipse SDK, delta pack and language packages?
2. Are they packaged separately?
3. Are they discontinued to be replaced by something else? what are the replacements for each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is huge differences between the internals of 3.7 and 4.4 with many changes to plugins - some new, some removed. What you have downloaded covers the whole of the core Eclipse.

`org.eclipse.update.xxx` is the old Eclipse update system which was replaced some time ago with the 'p2' install manager (lots of `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.xxx` plugins).

I think the help system was also reworked with `org.eclipse.help.appserver` removed and some more `org.eclipse.help.xxx` plugins added.

`org.eclipse.swt.carbon.macosx` that is the old Mac 32 Carbon UI which is no longer supported. Replaced with `org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.xxx` plugins.

`org.eclipse.swt.gtk.hpux.ia64_32` probably no longer supported.

I don't know about the language packs.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Is there some kind of a mapping guide or Eclipse migration guide which could have these clues? or posting questions on eclipse.org forums would be the best way forward?

Comment: I don't know of a list but have never looked. I generally use feature based builds which deal with most of this automatically.

Comment: What do you mean by "feature based builds"? Can you please elaborate? I'll also probably use it if that is simpler.

Comment: In a feature based build you just provide a list of features to include in the build. Each feature contains a list of plugins and nested features that make up the feature. The 'org.eclipse.sdk' feature, for example, lists everything in the Eclipse SDK.

Comment: I have posted a question about the jar files in language pack here: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1694064/#msg_1694064 but am not getting any response. Any idea how I could get inputs about it?

Comment: I got a reply from Thomas Schindl on the eclipse.org forum who shared a proper porting/migration guide - https://eclipse.org/eclipse/development/porting/4.2/incompatibilities.html#update-manager. This was what I was looking for.

Comment: still waiting for some info on missing language packs for packages that are still supported in 4.4...

Comment: You might do better asking a separate question about the language packs